# IntelliJ IDEA: change open with (associated application) preference

Tags: intellij-idea

I had created a `.tf` file when I did not have HCL plugin installed. Hence I associated that file to be opened with notepad++ . But now after installing the HCL plugin it still opens with notepad++.

How do I change this association so that the file gets opened in IntelliJ IDEA?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the extension from this list:

[image: associated]